# Pestañas deslizantes Android

Tags: android

Queria hacer que mis tabs (pestañas) se deslizen para los costados. Pero no encuentro algun tutorial que lo explique bien. Si me pueden pasar alguno se los agradezco.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que debes usar actualmente es un [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) :

Creas una instancia de TabLayout y agregas los elementos que deseas (pestañas)

```
TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText("Elemento A"));
tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText("Elemento B"));
tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText("Elemento C"));
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es un **[tutoríal](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/06/tablayout-como-anadir-pestanas-en-android/)** en español, trata de implementarlo y si tienes dudas pregunta.

Comment: estoy utilizando un FragmentTabHost, hay alguna posibildad de hacer deslizar las pestañas con esa propiedad y no tener que implementar un tabLayout?